# Discover which methods and classes were modified in a git commit?

Tags: ruby, git

I'm using a git repository to collect information about software evolution. I want to discover which classes and methods, in Ruby, were modified in a commit.

I know that with git log I can retrieve a list of modified files in a commit and then is possible to parsing those files to discover which methods were modified.

Does there exist some way in git or another tools to tell me which classes and methods were modified without manually parsing each file?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such a tool.

If you feel that this is a very useful tool, you can code it by using the gem [sorcerer](https://github.com/jimweirich/sorcerer) to evaluate your code and using [rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) to interface with git.

A way to avoid the need of a tool like this is to do small commits with good descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git diff <commit_1> <commit_2>` to find this information.

You'll want to determine the `<commit_1> and <commit_2>` hash values from `git log`

Also, you might consider using `gitk` (you'll need to install this) if you prefer a gui approach.

Comment: The problem is that I have a lot of commits to evaluate (3k~), so a gui approach is not possible. 
And the git diff will tell me wich lines was changed, so I will need to process this file.

Comment: I don't understand. Git diff provides you with the lines that changed between commits. Can't you run a bash script/ruby script to diff all of the commits and aggregate them into a total list of changes?

Comment: Yes, I can. But this list don't tell me which methods of a commit was changed. I am parsing each file to discover on which methods the modifications are, but I was wondering if exist a tool that do this job for me.

Answer (score 0):

What you want should be possible, but I know of no tool to do it off the top of my head. If I understand correctly, you want

Given list of code X, find the ruby method/class that contains X.

There are quite a few ruby code analysers out there that might provide a starting 
point. They are doing something much more complex than what you want.

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/code_metrics